# Make CSS Grid wrap from the end

Tags: css, css-grid

How to make css grid wrap to the next rows while starting from the end (from right on a `ltr` flow)?

**Current scenario**:

```js
const containerEl = document.getElementsByClassName('alphabet-container')[0];

new Array(26).fill(undefined).map((_, index) => String.fromCharCode(65 + index)).map(alphabet => document.createElement('button').appendChild(document.createTextNode(alphabet))).map(textChild => containerEl.appendChild(textChild.parentNode));
```

```css
.alphabet-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 4px;
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(48px, 1fr);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(48px, 1fr));
}
```

```html
<div class="alphabet-container"></div>
```

**Current vs desired**:
[image]

---

*Keywords: css grid, auto flow, auto columns, wrap reverse, wrap from end, wrap from right*

Comment: is there something to select even or odd indexed rows in row? if yes then it will be easy.

Comment: i suggest you look up for something called "grid-area" ...... let's you position in your own way

Comment: I don't believe there's anything in the currently supported Grid or Flex versions that provide this behavior. You'll need JS.

Comment: Yes, it's possible to select even/odd or any specific subset(s) of A-Z alphabets. The requirement is that when there's sufficient space, the columns should expand equally (i.e. _auto-fit_).

I am using Angular so pretty much any JS logic or template manipulation can be applied, but it should be clean enough.

Comment: `direction: rtl` on the container

Answer (score 0):

A small JS script that you run on screen resize can help you. The idea is to use a hidden element that will fill the first columns of the last row and the JS will dynamically calculate the values.

```js
const containerEl = document.getElementsByClassName('alphabet-container')[0];

new Array(26).fill(undefined).map((_, index) => String.fromCharCode(65 + index)).map(alphabet => document.createElement('button').appendChild(document.createTextNode(alphabet))).map(textChild => containerEl.appendChild(textChild.parentNode));

const p = document.querySelector('.alphabet-container');
var fix = function() {
  p.style.setProperty("--x", 'auto');
  p.style.setProperty("--y", 'auto');
  p.style.setProperty("--s", 'none');

  const g = window.getComputedStyle(p);
  const x = g.getPropertyValue("grid-template-rows").split(" ").length; /* get number of rows */
  if (x == 1) return;
  p.style.setProperty("--x", x);
  const y = g.getPropertyValue("grid-template-columns").split(" ").length; /* get number of columns */
  p.style.setProperty("--y", (x * y - 26));
  p.style.setProperty("--s", '" "');
}

fix()
window.onresize = function(event) {
  fix()
};
```

```css
.alphabet-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 4px;
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(48px, 1fr);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(48px, 1fr));
}

.alphabet-container::after {
  content: var(--s, none); /* we only show this whe needed (at least 2 rows) */
  grid-row: var(--x, auto); /* place at last row */
  grid-column: 1/span var(--y, auto); /*  place at first column and take N columns*/
}
```

```html
<div class="alphabet-container"></div>
```

Comment: When there's only one row, `::after` is pushing the elements to the right, killing the purpose of `auto-fit`.

Comment: @abdul-wahab yes to always have a right alignment, if you don't want this to happen add a condition `if(x == 1) return`

Comment: Now on large screen, it shows 27 columns, one empty column at the end.

Comment: Yes, now it looks fine.